# Can a Predicate be assigned a type?

Tags: rdf, owl, linked-data

I want to model lots of flows across a lattice of nodes.

[image]

The simple way is to simply model flow as a series of `a flowsTo b` relations - but this raises a problem where different flows cross a common lattice point, and what should remain as two independent flows merges into something less helpful.

So using the example above,

```
b flowsTo e
e flowsTo g
```

and

```
c flowsTo e
e flowsTo f
```

Describe two flows (the orange and purple ones) - but if modelled simply like this in RDF, loses the distinction between these two flows.

An alternative might be to have flow-specific predicates, such as `a flowsToNameX b`, and `a flowsToNameY c`, but as the number of flows increases, what I need is a way to collect all of these as a single collection.

Again, referring to the diagram, this might look like:

```
a RedFlowTo d
d RefFlowTo h
b OrangeFlowTo e
e OrangeFlowTo g
c PurpleFlowTo e
e PurpleFlowTo f
```

One way of doing this might be to define `flowsToNameX` and `flowsToNameY` as instances of some `flow` class, but I've not come across this pattern anywhere in the literature.

This works fine for 3 flows, but I'm looking at modelling thousands of these separate paths, across a similar number of nodes. So named instance (i.e. flow) -level predicates are fine, but I'd like to be able to work with them using a common set of interfaces so I can express concepts like `upstream` and `downstream` etc, and query the RDF using as general a form as possible.

This must be a common pattern, are there any best-practice approaches to modelling it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand well what you want to do, but can't you have `flowToNameX rdfs:subPropertyOf flowsTo`? Of course, you can also have `flowToNameXY rdfs:subPropertyOf flowsToNameX` and `flowToNameXZ rdfs:subPropertyOf flowsToNameX`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've added a diagram to help outline the problem - `rdfs:subPropertyOf` might fit the bill, but I'd have to understand the implications - and yes, I've not come across A-Box vs T-Box, but it's very much an instance vs class type distinction - I'd like to treat these (and tbh ALL) links as describing general concepts, but can't escape the fact that each one is an instance of some kind - and I want to try and enjoy a cake-and-eat it compromise between the two.

Normally, instances are treated as nodes, and it feels alien to apply that instantiation to predicates.

Comment: With your edited question, I'm even more convinced that you could just have a property hierarchy.

Comment: A statement A p B is sometimes described as an instance of p (because the extension of p is the set of all pairs (A, B) where A and B have types in the domain and range of p), so in a way instantiation works just the same way with predicates at the OWL level. At the RDF level, these look very different - so the OWL view might be better for your purposes.